# xslt to group xml based on element values

Tags: xslt

want to group request based on similar package id using manual XSLT
Here is input xml which contains `plan_id` on which it needs to be grouped

```
<subscriptions>
    <package>
        <package_plan>
            <plan_id>1111</plan_id>
            <plan_name>economy1</plan_name>
        </package_plan>
        <rate_channel>
            <rateid>1F1</rateid>
            <currency>USD</currency>
            <package_duration>monthly</package_duration>
            <price>3</price>
        </rate_channel>
    </package>
    <package>
        <package_plan>
            <plan_id>1111</plan_id>
            <plan_name>economy1</plan_name>
        </package_plan>
        <rate_channel>
            <rateid>1F2</rateid>
            <currency>USD</currency>
            <package_duration>quaterly</package_duration>
            <price>11</price>
        </rate_channel>
    </package>
    <package>
        <package_plan>
            <plan_id>2222</plan_id>
            <plan_name>economy2</plan_name>
        </package_plan>
        <rate_channel>
            <rateid>1F3</rateid>
            <currency>INR</currency>
            <package_duration>monthly</package_duration>
            <price>250</price>
        </rate_channel>
    </package>
</subscriptions>
```

Looking for output as:

```
<subscriptions>
    <package>
        <plan_id>1111</plan_id>
        <plan_name>economy1</plan_name>
        <channels>
            <rate_channel>
                <rateid>1F1</rateid>
                <currency>USD</currency>
                <package_duration>monthly</package_duration>
                <price>3</price>
            </rate_channel>
            <rate_channel>
                <rateid>1F2</rateid>
                <currency>USD</currency>
                <package_duration>quaterly</package_duration>
                <price>11</price>
            </rate_channel>
        </channels>
    </package>
    <package>
        <plan_id>2222</plan_id>
        <plan_name>economy2</plan_name>
        <channels>
            <rate_channel>
                <rateid>1F3</rateid>
                <currency>INR</currency>
                <package_duration>monthly</package_duration>
                <price>250</price>
            </rate_channel>
        </channels>
    </package>
</subscriptions>
```

I've been doing some search and reading the other posts, and I don't think they cover exactly what I want to do 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0 or above, or are you restricted to XSLT 1.0? If you can use XSLT 2.0, read up on [xsl:for-each-group](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-for-each-group). If you are restricted to XSLT 1.0, then upgrade to XSLT 2.0 (or 3.0!).... or read up on [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are the XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 solutions. Both the solutions use a different approach as rightly pointed by @Tim C in the comment.

**XSLT 1.0**

In case of XSLT 1.0, [muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) is used. A `<xsl:key>` needs to be defined to group the elements. In this case, `<plan_id>` is the key on which the grouping will be done.

```
<xsl:key name="plan" match="package" use="package_plan/plan_id" />
```

The `package` elements are matched accordingly and the grouped data is copied to the output.

```
<xsl:template match="package[generate-id() = generate-id(key('plan', package_plan/plan_id)[1])]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="varPlan" select="key('plan', package_plan/plan_id)" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$varPlan[1]/package_plan/plan_id" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$varPlan[1]/package_plan/plan_name" />
        <channels>
            <xsl:for-each select="$varPlan">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="rate_channel" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </channels>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The rest of the `<package>` elements are removed.

```
<xsl:template match="package" />
```

**XSLT 2.0**

In XSLT 2.0, `<xsl-for-each-group>` feature is available especially for grouping of  elements. In this case, using this feature and the `current-group()` function, grouping can be achieved.

```
<xsl:template match="subscriptions">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="package" group-by="package_plan/plan_id">
            <package>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[1]/package_plan/plan_id" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[1]/package_plan/plan_name" />
                <channels>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="rate_channel" />
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </channels>
            </package>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

In both the above cases, an `identity transform` template should be used to copy the data as is to the output.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanks Aniket for providing in detail, it really worked as expected.